# use environment variable or http header with mod_authnz_ldap

Tags: apache, saml, httpd.conf, shibboleth

I have an apache that already uses Shibboleth SP for authentication and am now trying to configure it to use mod_authnz_ldap for authorization.  I'm not positive this would work, but would I'd like to do is, get the user's ID (which shibboleth sets at env variable and header) and provide it to a ldap-filter, some thing like

Require ldap-filter &(uid=${ENV_UID})(department=marketing)

IE, the current user would only be authorized if he/she is in marketing.

Unfortunately the IDP can't expose this data (otherwise I would just use Shibboleth to do authorization).  Does anyone have experience with using environment variables or header values in mod_authnz_ldap?  Or any apache mods for that matter?  Is it possible?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

According the Apache Documentation for [mod_authnz_ldap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#requiredirectives), the use of expressions in LDAP require directives is available as of version 2.4.8.

Make sure you're running the latest Apache, if you are, try increasing the logging levels and double check some settings.

Edit: I tested the new functionality on 2.4.18, and there appears to be a regression in the new feature. I opened a [bug report](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59880) accordingly.